# How to call the Google Maps Distance Matrix API from an Android application using the ANDROID key

Tags: android, api, google-maps

Actually we are using in our applicaton the Google Distance Matrix into an Android Aplication using the following code:

```
String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?"
           + "origins=" + start.latitude + "," + start.longitude
           + "&destinations="     +waypoints+"&sensor=false&mode=driving&key=GOOGLE_key";

       HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
       HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();

       HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);


       HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);

   .........
   ......
   ...
```

We have to put a server key in the key parameter of the API url, instead the android key,  but it is restringed for specific ip directions.

We want to call the API using the android key, have someone any idea about how can archive this?

Comment: You can create the `Android key` for your project in the `google developer console`, and then put in `android key` instead of `server key`. For more details, please refer to [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#get_an_android_api_key).

Answer (score 4):

“The Google Maps Distance Matrix API will only work with a Server key.” (not Android key)
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/get-api-key#types-of-api-keys

You could also use clientId in Android app to authenticate, but that would be insecure because your client key could be stolen.

So the best way is to create an endpoint in your server that would act similar to a proxy. Android client makes request to your server. Your server makes request to Google API with server key. Response is then sent back to Android app.